# Sudden Shut down

Tags: windows, shutdown

My system has been experiencing unexpected shutdowns. I can't find any errors in my OS, and i have the same issues with Ubuntu. On occasion the system itself is running and the monitor shuts itself off

How could I troubleshoot this issue and how could i fix this?

My system specs are:

```
AMD A8-3870k,
Foxconn A75M
Corsair 2*4gb XMS3 RAM,
Kingston 64GB SSD,
Seagate 500GB HDD
```

Comment: What OS are you on right now? Have you tested your ram?

Comment: You should also check your cooling and PSU.

Answer (score 0):

Many customers have stated that this board has an issue with instant and continuous reboot problems.

The manufacture has replied that updating the bios will fix the issue.

The source is from one of my favorite spots Newegg. See link to your board and read reviews.

[feedback on Foxconn A75M mobo with vendor replies](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813186222)

Bios update is your remedy and contacting their support team looks effective and logical.